# UITest unable to find accessibilityLabel string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am trying to write a test that lets me know that my UIAlertController is on screen.  The test successfully displays the alert controller, but when I try to assert that it exists, I get a failure.  Why is the test failing?

Here is my alert controller code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Group the posts by...", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alertController.accessibilityLabel = "Grouping Options"
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is my test that fails:

```
func testThatTappingGroupByButtonPresentsAlertController() {
        let blogPostsNavigationBar = app.navigationBars["Blog Posts"]
        blogPostsNavigationBar.buttons["Group By"].tap()
        let sheetsQuery = app.sheets
        XCTAssert(sheetsQuery["Grouping Options"].exists)
}
```

The test works as expected until the assert.  I can see the alertController being presented in the simulator.  When I run `sheetsQuery.count`, I get 1, which is what I expect.  It seems like my alertController's accessibility label is not being found.  UIAlertController does not have an accessibilityIdentifier, so that's why I'm using accessibilityLabel.

I've also tried setting `alertController.isAccessibilityElement = true` but that didn't help either.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try setting the accessibility label on the alert controller's view instead? `alertController.view.accessibilityLabel = "Grouping Options"`? It might also be that you need to wait for the existence of the sheet rather than asserting immediately

Comment: Yes!  That fixed it.  If you want to leave that as an answer, maybe with some more info on why that fixes it, I'll accept the answer.  Thanks @KaneCheshire

Comment: Happy to although not really sure why it fixes it, I just remember having to do it before!